# Restart Riak nodes every time updated erlang mapreduce functions?

Tags: riak

Mapreduce-used functions in erlang modules has to be included in Riak in order to work.

Since I have a cluster, I have to restart all the nodes every time I made some changes to the source code in that function. I thought I could use:

```
riak-admin erl-reload
```

I was wrong.

How can I do this quickly? Not every time waiting for all the nodes to stop and start again...it takes about 20 seconds for five nodes. It doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that from a `riak attach` session using the network load `nl/1` shell function:

```
$ sudo riak attach
Remote Shell: Use "Ctrl-C a" to quit. q() or init:stop() will terminate the riak node.
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> nl(custom_mr).
abcast
```